# How do I properly test for a rejected promise using Jest?

Tags: reactjs, promise, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

#### Code

```
import { createUser } from '../services';
...
...

handleFormSubmit = () => {  
  this.setState({ loading: true });
  createUser()
    .then(() => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
      });
    })
    .catch(e => {
       this.setState({
         error: e,
       });
    });
};
```

#### Test

```
 it('rejects...', () => {
    const Container = createUserContainer(CreateUser);
    const wrapper = shallow(<Container />);  

    return wrapper.instance().handleFormSubmit()
      .catch(e => {
         console.log("State: ", wrapper.state());
         expect(e).toEqual('error');
      });
 });
```

#### Mock

```
export const createUser = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject('error');
  });
};
```

The test does force the code to go into the catch in the method. So the state does get set to 'error'.

But in my test, it doesn't do what I expect and wait for the Promise to reject before it tests for the state change.
I'm not sure what to try here, should I be using async/await?

So it's the `createUser` method I want to wait for but I'm not sure my implementation allows for this.

Comment: Hi.. how did you solve this issue? I have same code and needs to test after promise is completed.

Comment: FYI, you should not `reject` a string. You should reject an error, like `reject(new Error('error'))`.

Answer (score 74):

You should do something like this:

```js
it('rejects...', () => {
  const Container = createUserContainer(CreateUser);
  const wrapper = shallow(<Container />);  
  return expect(wrapper.instance().handleFormSubmit()).rejects.toEqual('error');
});
```

I think it is cleaner this way. You can see this approach [in the official docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async#rejects).

It's important to note that `.rejects` (and `.resolves`) returns a promise, which is returned in the example above so that jest knows to wait on it. If you don't return it, you MUST await it:

```js
it('rejects...', async () => {
  const Container = createUserContainer(CreateUser);
  const wrapper = shallow(<Container />); 
  await expect(wrapper.instance().handleFormSubmit()).rejects.toEqual('error');
});
```

Comment: This is the official way to check async errors. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Note: should probably make the method async and add await before expect (see linked official docs)

Comment: @Ahmed-Anas see the first example in the link. The one that starts with `t('tests error with rejects', () => {` not the other.

Comment: I had to make make a slight variation to make this work: `expect(wrapper.instance().handleFormSubmit()).rejects.toEqual(Error('error));`

Comment: @Jordi that depends on what your tested method returns

Comment: I've had success with using the syntax: ```expect(wrapper.instance().handleFormSubmit()).rejects.toThrow('error text')```

Comment: Worth noting that if you `await` code like `wrapper.instance().handleFormSubmit()`, a rejected promise will throw, so make sure you don't `await` when using `expect...rejects`

Comment: @killthrush Slight tweak to what you said. One *has* to await for correction functionality, but need to await the expect-chain, NOT the function inside the `expect()` argument. Awaiting that promise will, as you say, simply throw if rejected. In that case, one could simply treat the test as the normal `expect(() => { /* do something */ }).toThrow()`.

Answer (score 23):

The test fails because it's not aware that the subject is asynchronous. It can be fixed by using a `done` param or making the test function `async`.

Note it's also necessary to set the number of expected assertions so that the test will fail even if the catch branch is not taken.

`async`/`await` style:

```
 it('rejects...', async () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    const Container = createUserContainer(CreateUser);
    const wrapper = shallow(<Container />); 

    await wrapper.instance().handleFormSubmit()
      .catch(e => {
         console.log("State: ", wrapper.state());
         expect(e).toEqual('error');
      });
 });
```

Older style `done` param:

```
 it('rejects...', done => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    const Container = createUserContainer(CreateUser);
    const wrapper = shallow(<Container />);  

    wrapper.instance().handleFormSubmit()
      .catch(e => {
         console.log("State: ", wrapper.state());
         expect(e).toEqual('error');
         done();
      });
 });
```

[Asynchronous Testing Reference](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous.html)

[expect.assertions reference](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectassertionsnumber)

Comment: wouldn't this test give false positive if the function didn't throw?

Comment: @oyalhi no, it won't give a false positive. The line `expect.assertions(1)` tells jest that there will be an assertion so if the `catch` isn't triggered, jest will complain about the missing assertion

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks correct. Why do you say that it doesn't wait for the Promise to reject? The only difference I would make would be to make use of Jest's mocking capability, so change

#### Mock

```
export const createUser = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject('error');
  });
};
```

to

#### Test

```
jest.mock('../services');
const services = require('../services');

const createUser = jest.spyOn(services, "createUser");
createUser.mockRejectedValue("error");

...

it('rejects...', () => {
```

There's no need to have a separate Mock file

Comment: Note that your test can also confirm that state.loading is still set to true

Comment: What if the target code of the test needed to use "new services" thus you needed to do jest.doMock with a requireActual and override just a single function?

Answer (score 0):

In your code `handleFormSubmit` function should return Promise on which you can wait in your test. Also you need to return truthful data from success and error callback to resolve and reject the promise respectively.

```
handleFormSubmit = () => {  
  this.setState({ loading: true });
  return createUser()
    .then(() => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
      });
      return true;
    })
    .catch(e => {
       this.setState({
         error: e,
       });
       throw e;
    });
};
```

Here in your actual code you have caught the error in `catch` handler and trying to catch it further in out test case code.  Hence `catch` can not be chained further, while you can chain `then` multiple times.

For reference go through Promise documentations:
https://www.peterbe.com/plog/chainable-catches-in-a-promise

Comment: this didn't solve the issue. The code still goes into the catch, but the test still does not wait for the promise to fulfill before running the expects

Comment: My bad, Have updated the answer with documentation link. It will surely solve your problem