# Jest - how to expect for a thrown error on an async function, which gets caught

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I try to do this:

```
it('should throw an error', async ()=> {
    expect.assertions(1);
    try {
        await processor({}, MODULE_CONFIG)
    }
    catch (e) {
        expect(e).toBe("[TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')]")
    }
});
```

but it gives me this error:

[image]

I tried `toMatch` like in the docs, but it also give an error (one that seems even worse)

[image]

I tried using `rejects.tobe` instead, but i get the same error:

[image]

Comment: `e` is `instanceof TypeError` not string.

Comment: okay.... what do i do with that?

Comment: This is maybe a duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50821835/how-do-i-properly-test-for-a-rejected-promise-using-jest/64474313#64474313

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly test for a rejected promise using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50821835/how-do-i-properly-test-for-a-rejected-promise-using-jest)

Comment: no, i get the same error, see post

Comment: Try to use: expect(e).toThrow(TypeError) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46042613/how-to-test-the-type-of-a-thrown-exception-in-jest

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best answer I found seems to be getting the `message` property from the error (which is essentially just the error as a string), and comparing that.

`expect(e.message).toBe("Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')")`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with what you are trying to assert

I'm assuming that you are throwing an error from `processor`

If you are, and you are asserting what that error is, keep in mind that `typeof e === object`, not `string`

For example:

```js
function iThrownAnError() {
  throw new Error("ups");
}

describe("test a function that throws an error", () => {
  it("catches an error as expected", () => {
    try {
      iThrownAnError();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(typeof e); // logs object
      console.log(typeof "ups"); // logs string

      // the test pass
      expect(e).toStrictEqual(new Error("ups"));

      // the test would fail
      // Expected: "ups"
      // Received: [Error: ups]
      expect(e).toStrictEqual("ups");
    }
  });
});
```