# expect an async function to throw an error in jest

Tags: typescript, promise, jestjs

In jest, If I run the following code:

```
    await expect(async () => {
      const asyncFunc = async () => {
        return Promise.reject(new Error('Foo'))
      };
      await asyncFunc();
    }).toThrow();
```

I would expect this pass as the promise rejects with an error, but this passes. Is there a way to assert the async function throws a the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `async` function does not throw an exception. It [always returns a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43422932/1048572), which might get rejected.

So you'll need to [test that promise](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#resolves--rejects):

```
const asyncFunc = async () => {
  return Promise.reject(new Error('Foo'))
};
await expect(asyncFunc()).rejects.toEqual('Foo');
```

See also [How do I properly test for a rejected promise using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50821835/1048572) and [Best Way to Test Promises in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43037566/1048572).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [.rejects](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#rejects).

```
await expect(asyncFunc()).rejects.toThrow();
```

Note that the test needs to be `async` as well.